# Evaluate $\lim_{t \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{t} \right)^{\sqrt{t}} $

Tags: limits

I don't know what to do to solve this limit I tried to change the variable and to solve it by squeeze theorem but it doesn't work.
Let $u=\sqrt{t}$.

$(1 - 1/t)^{\sqrt{t}} = (1 - 1/u^2)^u$.
If $u>0$, we let $n^2<u<n+1$.  $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n < \left(1 - \frac{1}{u^ 2}\right)^u<\left[1- \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right]$$

Comment: Please show us your working.

Comment: It looks like you lost the exponent for the term in brackets.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When ever you have a variable as your exponent, it is a standard method to make a basechange and write it with basis $e$.

So $\left(1-\dfrac1t\right)^{\sqrt{t}}$ becomes $e^{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)\sqrt{t}}$.

And now you calulate (by continuity of the exponential function) the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty} \ln(1-\frac{1}{t})\sqrt{t}$. The result has to be then of course $e^{\text{that limit}}$.

Comment: It's a good hint now the nswer is obvious